# unityでキャラクター情報を管理するには

Tags: unity3d

初めてUnityでゲームを作ろうとしています。

現在キャラクターの情報をどのように管理するかで躓いています。

- キャラクターの名前(文字列型)
- キャッチコピー(文字列型)
- 紹介文(文字列型)
- 攻撃力(数値型)
- HP(数値型)

これらの情報をキャラクターごとに割り当てて管理したいと考えています。
ハードコーディングしてしまうと変更や修正が大変なので、データベースのように管理してそれらに問い合わせる(読み書きする)ような感じにしたいのですが、どのようにすればいいのかわかりません。
そもそもこのやり方が適切なのかどうか判断がつかず悩んでいます。

作ったものはHTML5(WebGL)用に書き出す予定なので、限定されるかもしれませんが何か良い方法があれば教えていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: ゲームを作ること自体が初めてでしょうか？Unityで作るのが初めてでしょうか？また、ゲームはどんなタイプのものでしょうか。キャラクター情報とは、ユーザーそれぞれが保有する例えばMMORPGのような想定でしょうか？それともポケモンのようにゲーム内で単にキャラクターの情報として保持するものでしょうか？データベースやサーバが必要となりそうなゲームでしょうか？　　質問文からは見えない部分が多いので、もう少し具体的に書くか、詳細を追記いただけると回答もつきやすくなるかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

ひとつの解として受け取ってください。
Jsonを使う前提で回答します。

Resources直下にデータを格納するディレクトリを設置し、

```
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"刹那",
    "detail":"セレスタルビーイングの若きエージェント",
    "name2":"ガンダム",
    "atk":1000,
    "hp":1000
}
```

みたいなデータ構造を作ります。
Resources.Loadを使ってデータは取得することができます。
サーバーを活用する場合も同様でサーバーサイドでJsonにデータを変換してしまい、
それにあわせて設計してやればいいと思います。
IDは今後必要になりますので設けておいたほうがよいかと思います。

あとはこのJsonデータをパースし、Classなり連想配列にしてやれば
柔軟に設計できると思います。

インスペクタで見れるようにしたい場合は自前でEditorを開発し、
専用のGUIを準備してください。
※データ参照とあわせて実装すればそう難しくはないはずです。

これで求めていた答えになれば幸いです。

Answer (score -1):

Unityを触ったことがないので可能かどうかわかりませんが、一般的に簡単なメタデータは、ファイルで管理するのがいいと思います。もちろんDBでもいいでしょう。
ファイルのデータ構造としてはJSONやXML、yaml、toml、CSVあたりでしょうか。何か考えがあれば自分でデータの保存形式を考えるのも良いかと思います。